# Проблема с Докер, Сайт localhost не отправил данных. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, docker

Собирал докер по гайду в ютубе (https://vladilen.notion.site/Docker-2021-a72201ec8573461c8a2e62e2fcf33aa3), имею файлы ниже. Запускаю так - make remove build run
Все проходит гладко, но когда я пытаюсь зайти на localhost:3000 (пробовал и localhost:80) то вижу картинку. [image: Страница недоступна] Сколько я б не перезагружал, не помогает, даже пк перезагружал, думал что некоторые приложения занимают порты, но нет...
[image: Info]
package.json:

```
{
  "name": "express-sample-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Makefile (для удобства):

```
build:
    cls
    npm install
    docker pull node
    docker build -t logsapp:env .

run:
    docker run -p 3000:80 -d --rm --name logsapp --env-file ./.env logsapp:env

stop:
    docker stop logsapp

remove:
    cls
    make stop
    docker container prune -f
    docker image prune -a -f
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV port 3000
EXPOSE $port
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

.env:

```
PORT=3000
```

.dockerignore:

```
Dockerfile
node_modules
.git
.idea
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs').promises

const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages'))

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const port = process.env.PORT ?? 3000
const logsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'data', 'logs.txt')

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await fs.readFile(logsPath, 'utf-8')
  const logs = data.split('\r\n').filter(i => !!i)
  res.render('index', {logs})
})

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const text = req.body.text
  await fs.appendFile(logsPath, `${text}\r\n`)
  res.redirect('/')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: а логи контейнера проверяли, может там ошибка есть?

Comment: Да, там все чисто, выводит только то что в консоль лог

Answer (score 0):

Ответ - каталог в Идеешке постоянно перемещался после запуска контейнера на раб стол, тем самым логи были чистые а через мгновение ничего уже и не было, логов тоже с ошибками... Вот так =)